# Suggestions for static library to avoid name collision

Tags: c++, static-libraries, static-linking

We have two libraries - lib1 and lib2. Both the libs use a third lib say lib3. If our customer uses lib1 and lib2 in the same application using static linking, the customer faces linking issues due to symbol collision as functions from lib3 are common in lib1 and lib2.

We have access to lib1, lib2, lib3 source codes. What changes should we do to avoid naming collisions?

After reading some posts, namespacing in C++ seems to solve the problem? But will it work in our case as lib3 will still be loaded twice?

Comment: Can't you use shared libraries?

Comment: We do publish shared libs too, but some customers want to use the static-libs too. We provide libs not the application so we are required to provide shared as well as static libs.

Comment: shouldn't lib1/lib2 doesn't include lib3 and just add as dependencies? (so your customer have to link with lib1/lib2/lib3).

Comment: lib3 contains our core code functions, not exposed as public API

Comment: We have a similar setup, where `program` depends on `lib1` and `lib2`, but `lib1` also depends on `lib2` and we have to use static libs. We don't link `lib1` with `lib2`, because `program` will take care of that. Can you do something similar and not link `lib1` and `lib2` with `lib3` and ask the consumer of those libs to the linking? You can ship `lib3` when you ship `lib1` and `lib2`.

Comment: lib1 and lib2 are independent in our case - offer different functionalities. So can't make one dependency of the other.

Comment: We meant, users who need lib1 but not lib2 link with lib1 and lib3, users who need lib2 link with lib2 and lib3, and user who need lib1 and lib2 link with all 3 libs.

Comment: As @Jarod42 said: when you deploy `lib1` you also deploy `lib3`; when you deploy `lib2` you also deploy `lib3`. Users of `lib1` will have to link with `lib1` and `lib3`; users of `lib2` will have to link with `lib2` and `lib3`; users of both will have to link with `lib1`, `lib2`, and `lib3`. You have to make sure the versions are compatible, but that's another issue.

Comment: The fact that lib3 is not exposed as public API is not really an issue. Share only lib3 without its header files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We finally fixed our problem using dynamic namespacing

First, define a macro for the namespace

```
#ifndef LIB_NAMESPACE
#define LIB_NAMESPACE SomeNameSpace
#endif
```

then add namespace around every class.

On compilation override the macro from the compiler command line e.g.

```
g++ -DMY_LIB_NAMESPACE=Lib1Namespace ...
g++ -DMY_LIB_NAMESPACE=Lib2Namespace ...
```

The only disadvantage is the size of the final executable will be slightly larger due to duplicate code.

Answer (score 3):

I'll leave an answer because this won't fit inside a comment.

As I understand you deploy some kind of software development kit for `lib1` and `lib2`. Each SDK contains some public headers and the `lib1` and `lib2` static libs. Both of these libraries are statically linked with `lib3`, which is an internal library.

So the SDKs could look something like this:

```
lib1 SDK
├── lib
│   ├── lib1.lib
├── headers
│   └── lib1.h

lib2 SDK
├── lib
│   ├── lib2.lib
├── headers
│   └── lib2.h
```

This works great except in the cases in which a customer needs both `lib1`, and `lib2`. Our suggestion was: don't statically link `lib3`, but deploy it inside the `lib1` and `lib2` SDKs. In this case your customers will simply have to update their build scripts to also link the already included `lib3`. So `lib1` customers will now link with `lib1` and `lib3`; `lib2` customers will now link with `lib2` and `lib3`. You already deploy `lib3` to the customers, only not as a stand-alone file, but included in the `lib1` and `lib2` libraries, so there's no big change here.

This means that customers who use both can pick one of the `lib3`s you provided and link against it.

Your SDKs now look like this:

```
lib2 SDK
├── lib
│   ├── lib2.lib
├── headers
│   └── lib2.h
├── dependencies
│   └── lib3.lib

(same for lib1)
```

There is now the risk that the customer will use `lib1 1.0` which depends on `lib3 1.0` and `lib2 2.0` which depends on `lib3 2.0`, with the two `lib3` versions being binary compatible (linking will succeed for both `lib1` and `lib2` regardless of the `lib3` version), but there are API changes between the two `lib3` versions that will generate runtime errors.

In this case you have to either be able to verify compatibility at build time (harder to do when you don't control the build process), or at run time (easy to do as long as the `lib3` API for doing this does not change).

You could also try to accommodate these customers by providing a common SDK for `lib1` and `lib2` which always includes a `lib3` version that is guaranteed to be compatible with both. However, this might not be a cost effective strategy for you.

EDIT: As @lalala mentioned, there are multi-threaded concerns that can make this unfeasible. For example, if `lib3` is not thread safe, making `lib1` and `lib2` use the same `lib3` will lead to race conditions, deadlocks, etc.

Comment: Great answer IMO

Comment: Threading safety might change (if lib3 is not thread safe and used by lib1 and lib2 in paralell)